# disable zoom on tap

Tags: javascript, ipad

I have an image bar which slides on move. But when i single tap on that bar its shows a magnifier. How i can disable that magnifier on tap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try returning NO here `– canPerformAction:withSender:`

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/canPerformAction:withSender:

Comment: Its a website. I need to disable magnifier in ipad's safari using javascript code.